# Virtual Machine can access internal network but not the internet

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am on a company computer with Windows7 installed on it. I installed VirtualBox on it too and installed Ubuntu on this virtual machine.

Now from inside the virtual machine (Ubuntu), I can access the company's internal websites and I receive replies to my pings to the DNS, gateway, and DHCP servers but I still cannot ping anything outside or access the internet from the web browser.

My configuration is as follows:

- On the host machine, there is one main ethernet adapter and one other host-adapter installed by virtual box. I have the host-adapter on default settings.
- On my guest machine, I only have one ethernet adapter set to default.

Any help is highly appreciated. I have tried just about everything I could think of. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that my company uses a proxy server and I had to define it in the virtual machine. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: How did you define it in the virtual machine?

Comment: Depends on the program I am using but I basically set the `http_proxy` environment variables and that worked for most things. Or you can globally define it using your network manager.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?  I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

I also had this sort of problem. But In my case, Ubuntu 11.10 was on VirtualBox on Windows 7 Enterprise, and tightly secured corporate network. But the issue, I think, was on host side.

What I did, is as follows:
    1. On VirtualBox's Network setting, choose "NAT", and **check** "Cable connected"
    2. On host machine's network adapter settings, re-check that "VirtualBox Host-Only Network" has DHCP, all other settings are set to automatic.
    3. On host machine's own "Local Area Connection", went to **"Properties">>"Sharing"**, and **check** "Allow other network users ...". And "OK"
    4. On virtual machine, Disconnect once by "Uncheck"ing "Enable Networking", then "check" again.

Bingo!, then Internet was working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Set your Virtual machine to use NAT, I bet that takes care of your problem.

Comment: I tried both NAT and bridging. Both have the exact same problem. Also, my ethernet connection (on the host machine) is configured to require authentication (preconfigured to automatically authenticate). Could this be the cause of the problem?

Comment: What kind of authentication?  That is very possible especially if your using the ethernet adapter that virtualbox sets up

Comment: If it's not working with NAT, then this is likely to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it's better to use CNTLM on your host to centralize your proxy settings connections.
Especially if you need an authentication.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have resolved this with other way.

Solving Proxy Problem

VirtualBox ->Machine -> Settings > Attached to: Bridged Adapter (Cable connected checked) -- ok
Disable Virtual Box Autho Generated Network Adapter in Windows.

And in Default Windows Ethernet you can paste you own other ip (But not same in Virtual Box Linux ip) if you want to Connect internet also with Windows Installed to HardWare

And In Virtual Box Linux  you have to construct ip adress and proxy setting appropriatelly